# Angular - View isn't updating in feature module 100% of the times when setting data from Observables

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http

I have a very weird issue and I've got no idea what could be wrong. I have a page that's lazy loaded and the template isn't updating despite the data being set. I'm not using `OnPush` or anything since it's a page and not a dumb component. I'm doing an http request, setting the data and then trying to loop this data, but the data only shows up in the template like once every 10 tries or something. As well as showing up just before the page is beginning to refresh when I click refresh the page.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bookings',
  templateUrl: './bookings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bookings.component.scss']
})

export class BookingsComponent implements OnInit {

  public ongoing: any[];
  public confirmed: any[];

  constructor(private appApi: AppApi, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {

        const ongoing$: Observable<any[]> = this.appApi.get(`/some-endpoint`).map(res => res.data);
        const confirmed$: Observable<any[]> = this.appApi.get(`/some-endpoints`, {isConfirmed: true}).map(res => res.data);

        Observable.forkJoin(ongoing$, confirmed$).subscribe((data) => {

          this.ongoing = data[0];
          this.confirmed = data[1];
        });
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Then I do this in the template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let booking of ongoing">
     <h1>{{booking?.title}}</h1>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But it gives me no `li` elements. The data is being set correctly because it shows up in the console when I log it and everything but something is really strange when it comes to actually updating the template... Any ideas what could cause this or how I can continue debugging? I've run out of ideas.

I've tried using:

- `this.cd.markForCheck()`
- `setTimeout(() => /* setting data here */)`
- `*ngFor="let booking of ongoing$ | async"` (and changing the data to be an observable of course)
- Having a `subscribe` for each http request instead of fork joining the two observables.
- Setting just any static values inside a subscribe, these also does **not** show up in the template. If I move it outside of the subscribe, then it works.

But **NOTHING** appears to be working.

What more can I do?

Comment: are you sure `ongoing` and `confirmed` both are returning a value?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof Yes. I can see it both in the console and the data shows up on refresh for a brief moment so it's there, but it's just not updating properly as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what it was, I had a Hotjar script which tracks user interaction on the page. And it ruins Angular's change detection completely for some reason. So simply removing that solved the issue.

I hope this helps someone else in the future trying to use Hotjar with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your template you have {{ongoing?.title}}, but it should actually be {{booking.title}}.

Comment: just a typo from all my testing. changed it now